# "Неделя здоровья". Нужны ли кавычки?

Tags: названия, кавычки

Необходимы ли кавычки, если словосочетание употребляется без родового слова. И нужно ли использовать заглавную букву? Прошу пояснить ответ.

1. Завершилась "Неделя здоровья".
2. Завершилась Неделя здоровья.
3. Завершилась неделя здоровья.
4. Завершилась "неделя здоровья".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если это название какого-то мероприятия, то кавычки нужно поставить, при этом все же нужно указать родовое слово, дабы было ясно, что это именно название.  Напр.: Педагогический проект "Неделя здоровья". Если, например, здоровью была посвящена неделя, то естественно, кавычки не нужны и писать следует со строчной. Напр.:Завершилась неделя здоровья.

Comment: А если цикл мероприятий, в рамках которого проводится неделя, посвященная здоровью?

Comment: Все зависит от того, что является названием этого цикла мероприятий - неделя здоровья или же мероприятие имеет другое название. Кавычки не нужны, если неделя здоровья, как вы отметили, проводится в рамках самого мероприятия, которое, по-видимому, уже имеет название.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ